# inView in framer-motion returns false when component is in viewPort in react image slider

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion, react-slideshow-image

Below is my slider component which renders the imageSlider in my app

```
const Slider = () => {
    // slider state and images data
    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
    const { sliderImages, sliderImagesLoading } = useAppContext();

    //framer-motion
    const [ref, inView] = useInView();
    const controls = useAnimation();
    const sliderVariants = {
        visible: { opatcity: 1, transition: { duration: 1 } },
        hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    };
    // autoscroll imageSlider
    let autoScroll = true;
    let myInterval;

    const setNext = () => {
        const sliderLength = sliderImages.length;
        currentSlide < sliderLength - 1 ? setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1) : setCurrentSlide(0);
    };

    const setPrev = () => {
        const sliderLength = sliderImages.length;
        currentSlide === 0 ? setCurrentSlide(sliderLength - 1) : setCurrentSlide(currentSlide - 1);
    };

    const auto = () => {
        myInterval = setInterval(setNext, 5000);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentSlide(0);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (autoScroll) {
            auto();
        }
        return () => clearInterval(myInterval);
    }, [currentSlide]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("inview" + inView);  // here inView logs false when component is visible and true when it is invisible
        if (!inView) { 
            controls.start("visible");
        }
    }, [controls, inView]);

    return (
        <div className="overflow-hidden w-full h-64 border-violet-800 border-t-4 border-b-4 ">
            <span
                className="absolute mt-20 left-0 bg-white w-12 h-24 flex items-center rounded-tr-md rounded-br-md z-50 "
                onClick={() => setPrev()}
            >
                <BsChevronLeft className="text-4xl  " />
            </span>
            <span
                className="absolute mt-20 right-0 bg-white w-12 h-24 flex items-center rounded-tl-md rounded-bl-md z-50"
                onClick={() => setNext()}
            >
                <BsChevronRight className="text-4xl" />
            </span>
            <div>
                {sliderImages.map((slide, index) => {
                    return (
                        <motion.div
                            key={slide.id}
                            ref={ref}
                            variants={sliderVariants}
                            initial="hidden"
                            animate={controls}
                        >
                            {currentSlide === index && (
                                <img src={slide.images[0]} className={`object-fill w-full`} />
                            )}
                        </motion.div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

my sliderImages is array of objects in format

```
    [{id:"id", name:"proudctname", images:["img1","img2","img3"]},
     {id:"id", name:"proudctname", images:["img1","img2","img3"]}
     {id:"id", name:"proudctname", images:["img1","img2","img3"]}]
```

So suggest some way how to do this. I want to set opacity of div containg the images to 0 initially and when it is in viewport, set opacity to 1 so that it creates a fade in effect.

I tried using useInView which comes from react-intersection-observer. but it is giving incorrect results. When my particular imageSlider comes in viewport it shows false and when it is removed from vp it shows true. It is totally opposite behaviour of expected.